# How to decode google search api results?

Tags: php, mysql, json, urldecode

I'm trying to insert google results to mysql utf-8 database.
But when i check inserted rows some characters seems weird.
For example "doctor's handbook" inserted as "doctor`&#39;`s handbook".
I tried htmlspecialchars_decode, urldecode but not worked.

```
$query="doctor's handbook";
$url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&"
    . "q=".urlencode($query)."&userip=78.160.152.204&rsz=large";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$body = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($body);
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($result->titleNoFormatting);
```

mysql_query("INSERT INTO files ( title ) VALUES ('$title')", $conn))

Comment: `& #39;` is *NOT* valid html entity. There should be no space in there, so no wonder it doesn't get decoded.

Comment: Actually no space there. Without space stack overflow shows it normal quote. So i added space.

Comment: use backticks to prevent that. ` &#39; `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey i solved the problem.

```
html_entity_decode($title,ENT_QUOTES);
```

**ENT_QUOTES** will convert both double and single quotes.